# How does Go resolve seemingly same types?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, types, uuid

I have a PostgreSQL database with 2 columns: id (UUID), company_url (varchar) with following values:

```
2fc35af4-5f5c-445e-86c5-01d93513b8be | https://test.com
2bf31b75-d1f3-4a9c-a530-73b714816e9e | https://test2.com
```

Here's the code to access the table using Go (error handling and credentials omited for simplicity):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
    connStr := "host= password= port= dbname= user="
    db, _ := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT * FROM companies;")

    for rows.Next() {
        // var id [16]byte // not ok
        var id uuid.UUID // ok
        var companyURL string

        rows.Scan(&id, &companyURL)
        fmt.Println(id, companyURL)
    }
}
```

There also exists a Go package for [UUIDs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/uuid). In its' source code the UUID is defined simply as

```
type UUID [16]byte
```

In the code above the **id** is typed using `uuid.UUID`, I tried to replace the type declaration in my code above (commented out with `not ok`) but instead of the correct value it returns an array of 16 zeroes. `uuid.UUID` returns correct id.

So my question is why such behaviour if `uuid.UUID` and `[16]byte` are of the same types? There are no binaries in uuid package nor `init()` function, nor is `Scan()` making any implicit changes.

Comment: `rows.Scan` can handle only the basic builtin types, plus `time.Time` and perhaps a couple others, but other than that it doesn't know how to decode the database data into a custom Go type. To be able to use custom Go types you have to have that type implement the `sql.Scanner` interface, then, `rows.Scan`, whenever it encounters a value of such a type, will invoke the interface and pass it the *raw bytes* so that the value can "scan itself". `rows.Scan` also returns an error, if you check it, you'll see that it's complaining that it doesn't know how to decode the data into `[16]byte`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, they are not the same types. They have the same [*underlying type*](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Underlying_types) though. `UUID` is different in that it [implements](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/uuid#UUID.Scan) the interfaces [`sql.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Scanner) and [`driver.Valuer`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql/driver#Valuer), so it can be used with the databases transparently.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like it. I had ran through the source code for `uuid` package again and found the `sql.go` file with the `Scan()` function.